# Невиртуальный деструктор и clang

Tags: c++, clang

Всем привет. Есть вот такой абстрактный класс, в котором я *осознанно* сделал деструктор не виртуальным:

```
#include <iostream>

#ifdef _MSC_VER
    #define __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ __FUNCSIG__
#endif

class Base
{
public:
    
    virtual void foo() = 0;
    
    ~Base()
    {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    }
};
```

Есть потомок:

```
class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    virtual void foo() override
    {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    }
    
    ~Derived()
    {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    }
};
```

И вызов деструктора:

```
Base * derived = new Derived;
delete derived;
```

Компилятор и запуск:

```
$clang --version

Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.28)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.6.0
Thread model: posix

$clang -lstdc++ -std=c++11 example.cpp -o example.out
```

Ожидаемое поведение этого кода — вызов деструктора только базового класса, так как вызов, очевидно, не виртуальный. В моем случае я получаю исключение на строке определения `~Base()`:

```
EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)
```

Опытным путем было выяснено, что проблема возникает если класс абстрактный. Если сделать метод `foo` виртуальным (`virtual void foo() {};`) то результат кода предсказуем:

```
Base::~Base()
```

Это баг компилятора или ожидаемое поведение? Если второе, то в чем смысл?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Такой вызов деструктора вызывает неопределенное поведение. Не гарантируется никакое "будет вызван только деструктор родителя" и т. п.

> в чем смысл?

Ну, видимо Clang так помогает вам обнаружить неопределенное поведение - и правильно делает.

---

Еще пример в тему:

```
struct A {int x = 0;};
struct B {int y = 0;};
struct C : A, B {};

int main()
{
    B *b = new C;
    delete b;
}
```

Вылетает с `free(): invalid pointer`. Домашнее задание - подумать, почему так происходит.

Comment: Хорошо, UB. В стандарте тоже написано что UB. Но вопрос, как раз в том, _почему_? Пример интересный, думаю, что delete пытается освободить нечто с типом `B` вместо `С`. Возможно, это следствие нарушения стандарта, но к пониманию это приближает не особо :-)

Comment: @АртёмОконечников Почему это сделали UB, или почему оно на практике крашится?

Comment: @АртёмОконечников В моем примере краш потому, что указатель указывает не на начало объекта, а в его середину, поэтому во free передается неправильный адрес. А если деструктор сделать виртуальным, то он как-то корректирует адрес перед передачей его во `free()`.

Comment: Да, почему оно UB и как это связано именно с деструктором. (То, что падает в следствии это ok). В моем понимании, UB это следствие некорректной манипуляции с памятью. Я бы тут как-то мог связать это с виртуальной таблицей, но ваш пример даже более показательный.

Comment: @АртёмОконечников Не всегда. UB - это по определению просто то, что стандарт объявляет UB. Иногда это действительно некорректная манипуляция памятью, а иногда просто желание левой пятки комитета по стандартизации.

Comment: Т.е. в моем примере, мне просто нужно принять на веру что вот это вот UB и всё тут, логики не искать? (это претензия к стандарту, не к вам). И просто варнингом компилятор не ограничивается, нужно мне ещё и код в рантайме крэшнуть :-)

Comment: @АртёмОконечников В целом да, все так. :Р

Answer (score 0):

1. Если деструктор не виртуальный, вы даете команду: "уничтожить объект
   базового класса(базовую часть объекта)   по  адресу `derived`". **А
   как уничтожать объект, который не возможно  создавать, так
   как класс абстрактный?..**(грубая
   ошибка). А если для наследника нужна память больше? Тогда и при
   условии, что базовый класс не абстрактный, это ошибка, связанная с
   не полным освобождением  захваченной памяти.
2. Если деструктор виртуальный,  "уничтожаем объект   по  адресу
   derived, каков бы он не был". Это и есть правильный подход(иметь виртуальный деструктор в абстрактном классе) .